# Is there a good approach to remove/add/hide/show a group of Fragments in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

My app is the following:

- First screen: login page (Fragment). After the user logs in, replaces it with the next screens.
- Other screens: within the app the user can see about 5 different Fragments, including a map, and they are all related.

I am having problems with the logout feature. I want to, regardless where in the app the user is, remove all possible Fragments when the user logs out. The problem is that my map may be hidden instead of removed.

I tried to implement:                   `fragmentManager.popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`
But it works buggy and intermittently. Sometimes it works, sometimes I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added` exception for my LoginFragment.

Is there a way to safely remove/stop/destroy a whole set of Fragments?
Let me know if there are better practices in this scenario.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I'm using this (safer?) method to clear my backstack:

```
private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
         manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

What I ended up doing was detaching all my fragments, so they'd be stopped. However, I had resources (audio) being initialized on the Fragment creation, and even detached they would still be running (playing the audio). I then came up with this method to be sure I'd free all my resources, and ran it with all my fragments:

```
public void safeDetach(Fragment f) {
    try {
        if (f.isAdded()) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .detach(f)
                .commit();
            f.onDestroy();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Now it works, no matter when or where I try to log out.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your fragments before adding them to your activity like this:

```
FooFragment fragment = new FooFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "foo");
transaction.addToBackStack("foo");
transaction.commit();
```

This way you can do many things when you find your fragment using the Fragment Manager:

```
currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("foo");
if (currentFragment != null) {
    //This means your fragment has been added to your backstack before
    if (currentFragment.isVisible ()) {
          // Is currently visible to the user
          if (currentFragment.isResumed())
              // Is resumed... etc...
    }
}
```

I usually pop from the backstack using the "immediate" method, just because I'm tagging the fragments and always know which one is currently available:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exactly what I need. I have the reference of all my Fragments, but when I log out I want to remove all of them at once. I hoped there was an elegant way, instead of doing if's to all of them.

Comment: You can iterate through the getBackStackEntryCount () like you're probably doing now. I think the only reason your audio keeps playing is because the popBackStack() method is asynchronous and it can time before the Fragments are destroyed.